# Creating a node class in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

So I'm fairly new to Java and programming and I was wondering how to create a node class?

So far I have:

```
public class ItemInfoNode{ 
    private ItemInfoNode next;
    private ItemInfoNode prev;
    private ItemInfo info;
    public ItemInfoNode(ItemInfo info, ItemInfoNode next, ItemInfoNode prev){
        info = info;
        next = next;
        prev = prev;
    }
    public void setInfo(ItemInfo info){
        info = info;

    }
    public void setNext(ItemInfoNode node){
        next = node;
    }
    public void setPrev(ItemInfoNode node){
        prev = node;
    }
    public ItemInfo getInfo(){
        return info;
    }
    public ItemInfoNode getNext(){
        return next;
    }
    public ItemInfoNode getPrev(){
        return prev;
    }

}
```

Pretty much the question asked for those methods so I put those down but, the next question asks me to refer to the head and tail of ItemInfoNode nodes. Just a bit confused here. Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for the help guys! I'm trying to create an "InsertInfo" method that puts information like the name, price, tag number, etc. Into one node. How do I go about creating this method?

So far I got this.. I have an Iteminfo constructor in a different class that has all of these but, I'm not sure how to use that/if I am even supposed to do..

```
public void InsertInfo(String name, String rfdnumber, double price, String original_position){

        head = new ItemInfoNode (Iteminfo, head);
    }
```

Comment: The class seems fine. The head and tail nodes should be defined in another class called `LinkedList` or similar.

Comment: How would I go about creating this class? More specifically, how do I create these head and null references.

Comment: Change `info = info;` to `this.info = info;`, same for rest of fields in constructor and setters.

Comment: If you have `ItemInfoNode node` typically, a `head` method returns `node` or `node.getInfo()` (according to the spec) and `tail` returns `node.getNext()`. Like cutting a snake's head and tail ;-)

Comment: Don't keep adding to a question that has been read and answered. People aren't going to monitor your quips on an old post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Welcome to Java!
This Nodes are like a blocks, they must be assembled to do amazing things!
In this particular case, your nodes can represent a list, a linked list, You can see an example here:

```
public class ItemLinkedList {
    private ItemInfoNode head;
    private ItemInfoNode tail;
    private int size = 0;

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void addBack(ItemInfo info) {
        size++;
        if (head == null) {
            head = new ItemInfoNode(info, null, null);
            tail = head;
        } else {
            ItemInfoNode node = new ItemInfoNode(info, null, tail);
            this.tail.next =node;
            this.tail = node;
        }
    }

    public void addFront(ItemInfo info) {
        size++;
        if (head == null) {
            head = new ItemInfoNode(info, null, null);
            tail = head;
        } else {
            ItemInfoNode node = new ItemInfoNode(info, head, null);
            this.head.prev = node;
            this.head = node;
        }
    }

    public ItemInfo removeBack() {
        ItemInfo result = null;
        if (head != null) {
            size--;
            result = tail.info;
            if (tail.prev != null) {
                tail.prev.next = null;
                tail = tail.prev;
            } else {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public ItemInfo removeFront() {
        ItemInfo result = null;
        if (head != null) {
            size--;
            result = head.info;
            if (head.next != null) {
                head.next.prev = null;
                head = head.next;
            } else {
                head = null;
                tail = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public class ItemInfoNode {

        private ItemInfoNode next;
        private ItemInfoNode prev;
        private ItemInfo info;

        public ItemInfoNode(ItemInfo info, ItemInfoNode next, ItemInfoNode prev) {
            this.info = info;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }

        public void setInfo(ItemInfo info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        public void setNext(ItemInfoNode node) {
            next = node;
        }

        public void setPrev(ItemInfoNode node) {
            prev = node;
        }

        public ItemInfo getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public ItemInfoNode getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public ItemInfoNode getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Declare ItemInfo as this:

```
public class ItemInfo {
    private String name;
    private String rfdNumber;
    private double price;
    private String originalPosition;

    public ItemInfo(){
    }

    public ItemInfo(String name, String rfdNumber, double price, String originalPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rfdNumber = rfdNumber;
        this.price = price;
        this.originalPosition = originalPosition;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRfdNumber() {
        return rfdNumber;
    }

    public void setRfdNumber(String rfdNumber) {
        this.rfdNumber = rfdNumber;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getOriginalPosition() {
        return originalPosition;
    }

    public void setOriginalPosition(String originalPosition) {
        this.originalPosition = originalPosition;
    }
}
```

Then, You can use your nodes inside the linked list like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ItemLinkedList list = new ItemLinkedList();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        list.addBack(new ItemInfo("name-"+i, "rfd"+i, i, String.valueOf(i)));

    }
    while (list.size() > 0){
        System.out.println(list.removeFront().getName());
    }
}
```